# missing 1 required positional argument error for fixture when softest.TestCase in inherited

Tags: python, pytest

I am getting error missing 1 required positional argument for fixture when i inherite softest.TestCase

note : if i remove softest.TestCase test will execute but failes when used.
my pytest code as below :

**Content of test_compyte.py**

```
import softest

class Testcompute (softest.TestCase):

    def test_compute(self,param1):
        print("param is ",param1)
        assert param1 > 4

if __name__ == '__main__':
    softest.main()
```

**Content of conftest.py**

```
import pytest
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

def pytest_addoption(parser):

    parser.addoption("--templatename", action="store", help="run all combinations")


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):

    if "param1" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if metafunc.config.getoption("templatename"):
            end = int(metafunc.config.getoption("templatename"))
        else:
            end = 1
        metafunc.parametrize("param1", range(end))
```

**Error logs**

```
self = <parameter.test_compute.Testcompute testMethod=test_compute>
method = <bound method Testcompute.test_compute of <parameter.test_compute.Testcompute testMethod=test_compute>>

    def _callTestMethod(self, method):
>       method()
E       TypeError: test_compute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param1'

 TypeError
================================================================ short test summary info =================================================================
FAILED test_compute.py::Testcompute::test_compute - TypeError: test_compute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param1'
1 failed in 0.22s
```

Comment: I would guess that `softest.TestCase` is not compatible with pytest fixtures, the same as `unittest.TestCase`. For this to work, `softest.TestCase` would have to know about pytest fixtures.

Comment: thanks for the input. I am abel to use the all funcation of softest.TestCase like soft_assert , soft_assertall. the problem is when i try to use the fixture name as arrugment for my test case with softest.Testcase inherited.

Comment: found work arround solucation : instead of inherting softest.TestCase. create object of softest.TestCase and it will work.
class Testcompute ():

    def test_compute(self,param1):
       case = softest.TestCase()
        print("param is ",param1)
        assert param1 > 4

if __name__ == '__main__':
    softest.main()

Comment: You could add this as an answer, it may help someone else.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, agree with you  . i am not getting option to add answer . I am getting only add comment option

Answer (score 0):

Work around solution: instead of inheriting `softest.TestCase`, create an object of `softest.TestCase` inside the test.

Updated content of *test_compyte.py*:

```py
class Testcompute: 
    def test_compute(self, param1): 
        case = softest.TestCase() 
        print("param is ", param1) 
        assert param1 > 4 

if name == 'main': 
    softest.main()
```